# Cannot set cookie in Controller or Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I am trying to implement a cookie compliance modal which lets the user accept or decline. When the user clicks accept, I set a cookie using a jQuery plugin by Carhartl (https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). When I use `$.cookie('cookieCompliant', 'true);` in the console, the cookie sets fine. However, the cookie will not set when used in my controller. I have tried vanilla JS and also Angular's `$cookie`, but none of them work. Is there a restriction to this? I also can't get `alert()` or `console.log` to work.

`MainController`

```
Main.controller("MainController", ['$scope', 'MainFactory', 'CookieFactory', function($scope, MainFactory, CookieFactory){

$scope.cookies = new CookieFactory();

$scope.siteSettings = new MainFactory();

$scope.agreeCookieCompliance = function(){
    $.cookie("cookieCompliant", "true");
    $('#cookieModal').modal("hide")
}

$scope.declineCookieCompliance = function(){
    window.location.href = "https://encrypted.google.com/";
}

$scope.checkCookieCompliance = function(){
    if($.cookie('cookieCompliant') === undefined){

        $('#cookieModal').modal("show");            
    }
}

$scope.checkCookieCompliance();

}]);
```

`index.php (modal)`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cookieModal"tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="display: block; padding-left: 17px;">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">This site uses cookies</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>This site uses cookies to give you the best possible experience. By clicking "Accept" you agree to the use of cookies.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="pull-left" style="line-height: 2.5;" href="http://www.whatarecookies.com/" target="_blank">What are Cookies?</a>
            <button type="button" ng-click="acceptCookieCompliance()" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Accept</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="declineCookieCompliance()" class="btn btn-danger">Decline</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Note: I am not using CookieFactory, it's only in there because I am frantically searching for a solution.

Comment: We can't answer without seeing your code. There is a lot of possible answers.

Comment: Okay, I've included my MainFactory, which is where I am trying to set/get the cookie.